# Как правильно создать docker machine на linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-machine

Следя инструкции с официального сайта, я скачал docker на ubuntu 20.04, никогда раньше не пользовался им. У меня возникла путаница при попытке создать docker machine, на этом сайте https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/ я прочитал, что нужно прописать команду

> docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev

На что мне выдается ошибка

> Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure
> VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"

Правильно ли я все делаю и необходимо ли устанавливать VBox, в инструкции к линуксу об этом ничего не было, зато к виндовсу было, может я что то путаю?
Как использовать команду docker-machine create на линуксе?

Comment: прямым текстом написано же

Comment: `--driver virtualbox` как бэ намекает нам, что будет использоваться вбокс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. После установки Докера проверить - создалась ли группа docker, внести туда юзера от которого собираетесь запускать контейнеры;
2. "VBoxManage not found" - необходимо установить Oracle VirtualBox для полноценной работы Docker